# How to set FrameLayout height to match one of the child component

Tags: android, android-layout, android-framelayout, android-layout-weight, android-layoutparams

I have the following framelayout containing a `TextView` and `ProgressBar`. At one given time, only one of them is shown. The `hideText` flag is initially set to false.

```
   <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_detail_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{model.text}"
            android:visibility="@{model.hideText}" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_loader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="@{!model.hideText}" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

The text in the `TextView` is fetched dynamically so the height of this component is unknown before runtime. When I set the `hideText` flag to `true`, The height of the frame layout shrinks to match the progress bar. However, I would like the frame layout to maintain it's initial height (ie that of the `TextView` and display the progress bar in the middle.

Is there any way to specify the `ProgressBar`'s `android:layout_height` property to match the TextView height?

Comment: Just Don't make `textview_detail_title` `GONE` make it `INVISIBLE` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need import View to your layout file.

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    ...
</data>
```

And than For text make this:

```
android:visibility="@{model.hideText == true ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

And for ProgressBar this:

```
android:visibility="@{model.hideText == true ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE}"
```